# Why does no one use filter_input()?

Tags: php, filter-input

Okay, I'm sure *some* people do use `filter_input()` but my point is that in the hundreds of thousands of lines of PHP that I have come across, I have never once seen it used, but rather just accessing the superglobals $_GET and $_POST.

I lie. I had seen it once, which is why I remembered that there was an alternative (possibly better?) way of accessing the input superglobals. But it took me a heck of a lot of searching just to find it - because every single tutorial or blog post on the interwebs uses `$_GET` and `$_POST` etc.

What am I missing? Why isn't everyone recommending to eschew the superglobals in favour of `filter_input()` as a best practice?

Or is `filter_input()` just useless cruft that seemed like a good idea in 5.2 but never really took root?

Comment: Probably everyone isn't aware. Could be a preferential thing. They're just a strange and funny animal.

Comment: The `filter_*` functions just provide a use-case limited number of filters with an inconvenient API. (Personally using them implicitly with e.g. `$_GET->url["link"]`.)

Comment: @mario I didn't know $_GET was an object that had filter methods available on it. Do you have a link to docs on that?

Comment: Well no, it isn't. But you can overlay one, which makes the superglobals a bit more useful: http://fossil.include-once.org/hybrid7/wiki/input

Comment: @mario that's a pretty cool library. Thanks for the link!